# Subset vector not containing word in piped operation in R (regex)

Tags: r, regex, stringr, piping

How do I subset a vector for elements that do not contain a word in a piped operation? (I'm really into piping)

I'm hoping there's some way to invert `str_subset`. In the following example, I'd like to just return the second element of `x` instead of the elements with `hi` in them:

```
library(stringr)
x <- c("hi", "bye", "hip")
x %>% 
    str_dup(2) %>%  # just an example operation
    str_subset("hi")  # I want to return the inverse of this
```

Comment: In package `stringi` there is `stri_subset_fixed("hi", negate = TRUE)`. It works, I have just tried it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `^(?!.*hi)` to assert string not contain `hi`; The regex uses negative look ahead `?!` and asserts the string doesn't contain a pattern `.*hi`:

```
x %>% 
    str_dup(2) %>%  # just an example operation
    str_subset("^(?!.*hi)")  
# [1] "byebye"
```

Or filter by reversing `str_detect`:

```
x %>% 
    str_dup(2) %>%  # just an example operation
    {.[!str_detect(., "hi")]}  
# [1] "byebye"
```